# Switching between CSS styles using the <option> tag

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a website where you can chose between different designs using javascript. I used [this](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml) as a guide. However, in the guide it uses the input tag to switch between different stylesheets, which makes it so that you need a button for each design. With several choices in design, it makes it inconvenient for me to have a button for each design. I'll like it to be a list where you chose from that list which design you wish to use, and from there click a submit button to chose that design. The code I used is provided below, but I need help to make it work.

HTML

```
<select name="theme">

 <option value="default">Default</option>
 <option value="blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="pink">Pink</option>

</select>
```

This is for the button version:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('default');return false;" name="theme" value="Default" id="default">

<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;" name="theme" value="Blue" id="blue">

<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('pink');return false;" name="theme" value="Pink" id="pink">

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;
var style_domain = "#" ;

// You do not need to customise anything below this line

function switch_style ( css_title )
{
// You may use this script on your site free of charge provided
// you do not remove this notice or the URL below. Script from
// http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml
  var i, link_tag ;
  for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
    i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
    if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
      link_tag[i].title) {
      link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
      if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
        link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
      }
    }
    set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
      style_cookie_duration, style_domain );
  }
}
function set_style_from_cookie()
{
  var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
  if (css_title.length) {
    switch_style( css_title );
  }
}
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `onchange` jQuery handler and pass `value` to `switch_style` function.

Comment: Like this?

<select name="theme" onchange="switch_style(this.value); return false;">

     <option value="default" id="default">Default</option>
     <option value="blue" id="blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="pink" id="pink">Pink</option>

</select>

Comment: Thanks! It helped, it helped. Now it automatically changes to the theme on the list. HOWEVER, I need it to change when you click on the "submit"-button and not when you just click on somenthing on the list.

Comment: @Chris - Then You need to - Wrap HTML code inside a HTML Form Element - and then - add Event handler for `onsubmit` Event.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that. Could you further explain?

Answer (score 0):

In pure Javascript you can use this:

HTML:

```
<select id="changestyle" name="theme" onchange="changeStyle()">
 <option value="default">Default</option>
 <option value="blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function changeStyle(){
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("changestyle");
    var myValue = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value;
    alert( 'myValue = ' + myValue );
}
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sundaze/k1s1rmkp/

In JQuery its a little less typing, but you need to load the JQuery library:

HTML:

```
<select id="changestyle" name="theme">
 <option value="default">Default</option>
 <option value="blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#changestyle').change(function(){
      alert($('#changestyle').val());
    });

});
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sundaze/jjhLzczf/2/

Greetings 
Mike